How to return all MATCH function result in a list?
Data



Value




G


U


A


E


A


O


P



I used match function to find the relative position.  However, I want to find all the relative position of "A" and expected to return the following table:








3


5



Thanks.

Use filter(), like this:
=filter(sequence(rows(A2:A)), A2:A = "A")

See filter() and sequence().

Appreciated your help, saved me hours!

Note: @doubleunary's answer is good and works for both ranges and arrays.
Variation below applies only to ranges.
=FILTER(ROW(A2:A)-1,A2:A="A")
 FILTER  ROW
=FILTER(ROW(range)-skip,range=val) 
  val  →  Value to match in range. 
  skip →  Number of rows above range.
          eg. if range=A2:A  then skip=1
              if range=A73:A then skip=72

Also appreciated your help, will come back give you a merit when i have 15 reputation :)
